# malformedURLException no protocol on Image

Tags: java

i used the following code:

```
g.drawImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(new  
URL(".\\mouseicon1.bmp")), MouseX,MouseY,null);
```

and the image file(`mouseicon1.bmp`) is in the same package, but it throws this exception:

```
java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: .\mouseicon1.bmp
    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at (insertnameofpackagehere).launch$Board.paint(launch.java:48)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.BufferStrategyPaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.seqPaintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.SystemEventQueueUtilities$ComponentWorkRequest.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: What do you think `new URL` does? Why do you think so?

Answer (score 3):

As the error says, URL expects a protocol. For local files you can use file:// as protocol when using a URL. Or you can convert a File to a URL:

```
new File(path).toURI().toURL();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are only looking for a file on your local computer you should probably use the following method

```
ToolKit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(String filename);
```

but if you really want to use URL then I believe this would accomplish the same thing

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(new URL("file://./test.bmp"))
```

Comment: No no no... do not do this.

Comment: For one, the uniform path separator is "/" or File.separator.